# how to responsive webcam image webcam working fine but not responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, webcam

How to use responsive webcam image? I used `webcam.js` and defined `height` and `width` in javascript. I'm trying but captured image is not responsive.

**My js code:**

```
function setwebcam()
{
  //$("#set_cam").hide();
  //$("#take_photo").show();
  Webcam.set({
    width: 320,
    height: 480,
    align:'center',
    image_format: 'jpeg',
    jpeg_quality: 100
  });
  Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );        
}

function setcoord()
{    
  $('#cropbox').Jcrop({
    aspectRatio: 1,
    onSelect: updateCoords
  }); 
}

function updateCoords(c)
{
  $('#x').val(c.x);
  $('#y').val(c.y);
  $('#w').val(c.w);
  $('#h').val(c.h);
}
```

**HTML code :**

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="cap_div" style="background-color:#f9f9f9; 
                                          box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #ccc;
                                          margin-bottom:95px;
                                          margin-top:20px;
                                          display:none;"   >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-md-12"  id="my_camera">
      
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 class="text-center" style="font-size:36px;  color:#000000;">
    Click on capture to get image
  </h3>
  
  <hr>
  <div class="row" style="z-index: 10; padding-bottom:  1em;">
    <p class="text-center">
      <a onClick="take_snapshot();" id="take_photo" class="browse_btn flat-button orange-flat-button btn btn-warning2 btn-lg" >
        <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Capture
      </a>
      <span class="visible-xs visible-sm"  id="oder" style="padding:10px 0;">
        - or -
      </span>
    </p>
  
      
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve this?

Webcam is working fine but not the responsiveness.
Kindly help.

Comment: I took comment out of the question: "Well, how about adding more details. Like, what are you trying to accomplish, how are you doing it, what difficulties you have found with the approach, another approaches you have tried, etc. In summary, without code isn't a good question neither is with just code. Search for the balance!"

Comment: What do you mean by "responsive"? Do you only see a still image? Do you get any error message?

Answer (score 1):

you can add the css breakpoint

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
    #my_camera video {
        max-width: 80%;
        max-height: 80%;
    }

    #results img {
        max-width: 80%;
        max-height: 80%;

    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe also explaining the cause of the problem might create a better answer.